# MEAN Stack: Expressjs Routes with query parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I have two separate schemas- 1. User 2. Plans. I am trying to find all the plans that belong to a user, but doing a get request using query parameters is not working.Please help.

Here is my query

http://localhost:8080/api/plans/search?userId=56bd16761e6bb0e5b2b43c9b

I get all the plans via this route so that is working.

http://localhost:8080/api/plans/

Here is my Plan Model

```
var PlanSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {type: String},
   userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   spots:[{
     name: {type: String},
     category: {type: String},
     address: {type: String},
     hours: {type: String},
     phone: {type: String},
     website: {type: String},
     notes: {type: String},
     imageUrl: {type: String},
     dayNumber: {type: Number}
   }]
});
```

Here is my Plans Route.

```
    PlansController.get('/', function(req, res){
  Plan.find({}, function(err, plans){
  res.json(plans);
  });
});

PlansController.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  Plan.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, plan){
    res.json(plan);
  });
});


PlansController.get('/search', function(req, res){
  Plan.find({ userId: req.query.userId }, function (err, plans){
    res.json(plans);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? In the terminal I get this,

GET /api/plans/search?userId=56bd16761e6bb0e5b2b43c9b 200 7.047 ms - -

Comment: If you do `console.log(req.query.userId)` what do you get?

Comment: @AshleyB Where would console.log output? Sorry I am new to node.There is nothing on the terminal when I make the request if terminal is where it is supposed to log errors.

Comment: Just at the start of your `/search` route (before the `Plan.find(..)`)

Comment: @AshleyB I mean I did that but its not outputting anything. Here is the snippet    `PlansController.get('/search', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query.userId);
  res.json(req.query.userId);
  Plan.find({ userId: req.query.userId }, function (err, plans){
    res.json(plans);
  });
});`

Comment: I think I figured it out. since search route looks similar to /:id route, it kept pulling that route for search strings. Search Route has to be included before the /:id route.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. since search route looks similar to /:id route, it keeps thinking of search strings as IDs and keeps using the id route.  Search Route has to be included before the /:id route.

Here is the updated code.

```
PlansController.get('/search', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query.userId);
  Plan.find({ userId: req.query.userId }, function (err, plans){
    console.log(plans);

    res.json(plans);
  });
});

PlansController.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  Plan.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, plan){
    res.json(plan);
  });
});
```